# How to add a row (with NA in each column) for each missing number in consecutive participant IDs?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a participant ID variable and several other variables. Participant IDs are consecutive (e.g. from 1-5), but some IDs are missing. I need to add a row for each missing ID; the ID variable should display the missing ID; and all other variables = NA.

Example:
I have: (possible IDs 1-5)

```
ID       PN1       PN2
1         2         5
2         3         4
4         6         2      
5         2         7
```

I need:

```
ID        V1       V2
1         2         5
2         3         4
3         NA        NA
4         6         2      
5         2         7
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 4, 5),
                 V1 = c(2, 3, 6, 2),
                 V2 = c(5,4,2,7))
```

Hope that someone can help! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Use `tidyr:: complete(df, ID = min(ID):max(ID))`

Comment: @akrun can you just add that as an answer?

Comment: It is a common duplicate.  So, i tagged as dupe

Answer (score 1):

Another (**base R**) approach using `merge`

```
merge(df, list(ID=1:nrow(df)), by="ID", all=T)
  ID V1 V2
1  1  2  5
2  2  3  4
3  3 NA NA
4  4  6  2
5  5  2  7
```